# I need those authors of the cell B which are not followed by other authors in other cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How could i get single Authors?

[image]

Comment: Use Excel's simple filter

Comment: What have you tried? Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question.

Comment: Data is too much, i need formula

Comment: Use `=IF(COUNTA(B1:D1)=1,B1,"")` and drag down.

Comment: Thank You, worked